# Wrap functions and return the final value

Tags: python, wrapper

I have a wrapper function which takes 2 functions as parameters. Both the function returns some value.

```
def wrapper(func, some_arg):
    def wrap(function, *args, **kwds):
        util_function(some_arg, *args, **kwargs)
        function(*args, **kwds)   //resultB
    return lambda *x,**k: wrap(func, *x, **k)
    //return resultB
```

Usage -

```
def exposed_function(argA, argB):
    wrapper(original_function)(arg1=argA, arg2=argB)
```

The user can will use exposed_function

I have to return resultB as the final output. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want `wrapper` to return `resultB`, or you want wrapper to return a function that returns `resultB` when called?  Please show an example of how you intend to use `wrapper`.

Comment: I am using wrapper as a normal function. <\br> Example - res = wrapper(method1, method2). I want res = resultB

Comment: That doesn't answer BrenBarn's question: do you want `wrapper` to return `resultB`, or do you want to return `wrap` from `wrapper`, and `wrap` returns `resultB`?

Comment: @Evert - both implementations would work for me.

Comment: @Pulkit: If you just want to return `resultB`, why are you defining `wrap` and your lambda at all?  Just do `resultA = pre()` and then `return func(resultA, *args, **kwargs)`, directly in the body of `wrapper`.

Comment: @BrenBarn - It's because pre() is an utility functionality which I don't want to expose to the users. It will be executed before the actual function call. The user will only have to call the original function

Comment: @Pulkit: Your description does not make sense.  If the way you are using `wrapper` is to call `res = wrapper(somePre, someFunc)`, then you are exposing `somePre`.  Again, please add sample code to your question showing how you intend `wrapper` to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but it seems like you just want to add the line `return resultB` at the end of the `wrap` function.

i.e.

```
def wrapper(func, pre):
    def wrap(function, *args, **kwds):
        resultA = pre()
        resultB = function(resultA, *args, **kwds)
        return resultB                                # <== newline

    return lambda *x,**k: wrap(func, *x, **k)
```

Then this could be used as

```
wrapped_func = wrapper(func1, func2)
wrapped_resultB = wrapped_func(args, kwds)
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Here lambda is executing the functions. I can only return the result after lambda is executed